# Can this Rego policy be simplified

Tags: opa, rego

I have this Rego policy that I want to simplify (fewer lines of code) more if possible especially the two findings blocks. I tried but failed miserably given that I'm a Rego noob.

```java
package test

compliant(resource) {
  resource.good
}

findings[x] {
    resource := input.resources[_]
    compliant(resource)
    x := {
        "compliant": true,
        "resource": resource,
    }
}

findings[x] {
    resource := input.resources[_]
    not compliant(resource)
    x := {
        "compliant": false,
        "resource": resource,
    }
}
```

Link to the OPA playground

https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/0xYWI7Q0fZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to output both the `true` and `false` evaluations.

You can introduce a helper function that will allow you to display both

```
package test

f(x) := true { compliant(x) } 
f(x) := false { not compliant(x) } 

compliant(resource) {
  resource.good
}

findings[x] {
    resource := input.resources[_]
    x := {
        "compliant": f(resource),
        "resource": resource,
    }
}
```